# How do I use the value from the latest insert using mysql_insert_id in subsequent MULTIPLE insert statements (in PHP and MYSQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add the value of the latest insert from TABLE1 to a subsequent MULTIPLE insert statement into TABLE2 which includes multiple entries - however in MySQL I am just getting a 0 (zero) for each entry added into TABLE2.

I know I need to store the `mysql_insert_id` in a variable after the first MySQL query has been executed. So I have included a variable called `$post_id` right after the first `mysql_query()` statement as follows:

```php
// If the submit button is pressed in the HTML form
if (isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {
    // First SQL Statement
    if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "SQL 1 SUCCESS! 1 record added<br/>";

    // A variable to store the id from the last MySQL query
    // This is the first time I have declared this variable
    $post_id = mysql_insert_id();

    // Second SQL Statement which utilises the variable
    if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
     {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "SQL 2 SUCCESS! 1 record added<br/>";
    echo "Finito!<br/>";
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

This SQL multiple insert statement into TABLE2 I have written is as follows:

```php
$sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    VALUES
    ($post_id,'key 1','value 1'),
    ($post_id,'key 2','value 2'),
    ($post_id,'key 3','value 3')
";
```

However, in spite of all of this (which looks correct) when I ACTUALLY look in MySQL, the post_id for EVERY entry in TABLE2 comes out as 0 (zero)?

Where am I going wrong?! HELP!

Comment: Obviously `$post_id` **is** `0`, so what do you wonder about? See http://php.net/mysql_insert_id .

Comment: $sql1 is nothing special, TABLE1 includes an AUTO_INCREMENT field and is as follows: `$sql1="INSERT INTO TABLE1 (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (1,'data1','data2')";`

Comment: What is the database definition of `TABLE1`? Please add it to your question. What does give `var_dump($post_id)`? What does `var_dump($sql2)` give? How can you build `$sql2` before getting `$post_id`? Please add `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your script.

Comment: I found the answer in the end! I realised that because I placed the `$sql2` string statement BEFORE the `$post_id = mysql_insert_id();` then PHP could not insert it into the code. So the correct way to do it is:

Comment: This works...

`if (isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {
    // First SQL Statement
    if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "SQL 1 SUCCESS! 1 record added<br/>";
    $post_id = mysql_insert_id();

    $sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    VALUES
    ($post_id,'key 1','value 1'),
    ($post_id,'key 2','value 2'),
    ($post_id,'key 3','value 3')
    ";

    // Second SQL Statement which utilises the variable
    if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
     {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the end! I realised that because I placed the `$sql2` string statement BEFORE the `$post_id = mysql_insert_id();` then PHP could not insert it into the code. So the correct way to do it is:

```
// If the submit button is pressed in the HTML form
if (isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {
// First SQL Statement
if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "SQL 1 SUCCESS! 1 record added<br/>";

// A variable to store the id from the last MySQL query
// This is the first time I have declared this variable
$post_id = mysql_insert_id();

// Place the SQL statement AFTER the mysql_insert_id() variable
$sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES
($post_id,'key 1','value 1'),
($post_id,'key 2','value 2'),
($post_id,'key 3','value 3')
";

// Second SQL Statement which utilises the variable
if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
 {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "SQL 2 SUCCESS! 1 record added<br/>";
echo "Finito!<br/>";
mysql_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a stupid question but it's not clear from your code: are you inserting the `$post_id` value into the `$sql2` string?

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    VALUES
    (" . $post_id . ",'key 1','value 1'),
    (" . $post_id . ",'key 2','value 2'),
    (" . $post_id . ",'key 3','value 3') ";
```

Comment: Yes correct - I am inserting the $post_id into the $sql2 string! Should I be doing it in the way you have written above or was my way an equally valid example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    VALUES
    ({$post_id},'key 1','value 1'),
    ({$post_id},'key 2','value 2'),
    ({$post_id},'key 3','value 3')
";
```